# webpack: possible to delete/remove async script tags added by require.ensure()?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am working on an mobile app where i made a router, which loads the Scene-Controllers with require.ensure().

With every new route called, a new async script tag is loaded into the head-tag

I don't need caching, but i want a low memory footprint (it is a hybrid app).
Is there a way to delete the deprecated tags, or is there any completely other approach?